# How to use the Vulkan graphics backend in the Stride game engine?

Tags: c#, vulkan, stride

What do I have to do in order to run my Stride game on the Vulkan graphics platform?

The documentation section seems to be outdated, the drop-down doesn't exist anymore:
https://doc.stride3d.net/latest/en/manual/platforms/index.html#set-the-graphics-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Stride 4.0 you can add the `StrideGraphicsApi` property to the top-level executable project. For example, add this line in the first `PropertyGroup` of the .csproj file:

```
<StrideGraphicsApi>Vulkan</StrideGraphicsApi>
```

Valid values are:

```
Null
Direct3D11
Direct3D12
OpenGL
OpenGLES
Vulkan
```